# shiny r: numericInput from the uploaded data

Tags: r, shiny

Ive just started using shiny and got the following **basic** questions.

1) The uploaded longitudinal data includes the column with Treatment names (e.g. A,B,C,D) and the other one includes corresponding numeric codes: e.g. 1,2,4,6. The coding might be different depending on the data uploaded. Each treatments is administrated on group of patients.

I want to use numeric codes to select treatments to be compared, sort of numericInput(). I need the list to be updated according to the coding in the actual dataset provided. So far I did it with numericInput() assuming the coding will be between 1 and 10 (see code below).

2) What If I want to select according to Treatment names (here A,B,C,D), which may differ among the datasets of interest?

Help much appreciated.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
## Data reactives:
uploaded_Data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input $ data
    if(is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    read.csv(file = inFile $ datapath,
             header=TRUE)

output $ raw_data <- renderTable({
    uploaded_Data()
})## for table


})

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel(''),
sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('data', 'File to upload (.csv only):',
              accept=c('.csv')),
    tags $ hr(),
    h4('Select treatments:'),
    numericInput('T1','Treatment1 code:',1, min=1, max=10, step=1),
    numericInput('T2','Treatment2 code:',2, min=2, max=10, step=1)
    ),

## Option for tabsets:
mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('Uploaded Data',
                 tableOutput('raw_data'))
        )
    )
))## overall
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you're asking is how to render a dynamic UI input based on uploaded data?

If that is the case then try integrating the following strategy into your app:

server.R:

```
#incomplete example
output$groupsToCompare <- renderUI({
  data <- uploaded_data()
  if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)} #This prevents an error if no data is loaded

  #In this example I will use selectInput, but you can also use checkboxInput or whatever really
  selectInput(inputId = 'selectedGroups', label = 'Select which groups to compare', choices = unique(data$treatments), multiple = TRUE)
})

#an example of how to use this input object
output$dataToShow <- renderTable ({
  data <- uploaded_data()
  if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

  #subset the data of interest; There are MANY ways to do this, I'm being verbose
  subsetData <- subset(data, input$selectedGroups)

  #alternatively, you could do data[input$selectedGroups]
  return(subsetData)
})
```

ui.R:

```
#incomplete example
uiOutput('selectedGroups')
```

This will dynamically generate a list of unique factors which can be selected as inputs. In your case, it will either generate a list of "A", "B", "C", "D" or a numeric factor list. These inputs can be used to subset your data, or select certain variables for whatever you can dream of. I think that this answers both of your questions, but if not please let me know so I can clarify. I haven't tested the `selectInput` with `multiple = TRUE` before, but I imagine it will work just fine. This will feel unusual at first, as you're basically setting up a UI element in server.R, where you're used to building the UI in ui.R, but once you do it a couple of times it gets gravy.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the `updateCheckboxGroupInput()`-function could be helpful

In **server.R**:

First change `shinyServer(function(input, output) ...` to `shinyServer(function(input, output, session) ...`

than add:

```
observe({
    x <- uploaded_Data()
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             inputID = "selectedTreatments",
                             label = "Select which groups to compare",
                             choices = unique(x$treatments), # treatment columns
                             selected = unique(x$treatments),
                             inline = FALSE)
})
```

In **ui.R** in the `sidebarPanel()` add to have

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'selectedTreatments',
                   label = 'no treatments to select yet',
                   choices = 1)
```

This creates a dummy checkbox, which will be replaced with the treatments ,after uploading the file. The observe function makes the 'update'-process invisible. The numeric inputs can be done analogously.

Feedback would be nice because I'm starting to learn it myself and had the same problem. This solution worked for me. I dont know if there's a way to let the checkbox appear only when the file is uploaded.